# Tor on Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: windows, proxy, python, tor, google-app-engine

I have installed [Google App Engine SDK for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) on Windows 8.1. I use [Vidalia Bridge Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) and the Chrome extension [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm?hl=en) to access the net through Tor. But the problem seem to be it doesn't change the *system* proxy setting and for any application I need to change its setting separately. The Preferences of Google App Engine Launcher has Deployment Server option:

[image]

But I don't know what to enter there.

Desperate!